# Getting the author name on author archive page inside WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making template for archives in WordPress website, but my template will not work for author name on author archive.

I have this:

```
<?php if (is_category('')) { ?>
<?php single_cat_title(); ?>

<?php } elseif (is_author('')) { ?>
<?php get_userdata( get_query_var('author') );?>

<?php } elseif (is_day('')) { ?>
<?php echo get_the_time('F j, Y'); ?>

<?php } elseif (is_month('')) { ?>
<?php echo get_the_time('F Y'); ?>

<?php } elseif (is_year('')) { ?>
<?php echo get_the_time('Y'); ?>

<?php } elseif (is_tag('')) { ?>
<?php echo single_tag_title(''); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

This part will not work:

```
<?php } elseif (is_author('')) { ?>
<?php get_userdata( get_query_var('author') );?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're using in is_author returns a user object. It doesn't output anything.

Correct usage would be:

```
<?php 
// Get current author.
$curauth = ( get_query_var( 'author_name' ) ) ? get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) ) : get_userdata( get_query_var( 'author' ) ); ?>

Author: <?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?>
```

Also the empty string isn't necessary with is_category etc.

Comment: You don't say where are defined $author_name & $author ?

Comment: @gordie While I appreciate your point, I must make you aware that it's based on code from the WordPress codex for author templates. It was the official recommended way of doing things as seen here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates. I've chosen to make things clearer by using the `get_query_var()` variation however I must point out that the previous method, to the best of my knowledge, was functional. Furthermore the answer was 5 years old.

Answer (score 3):

WordPress supports an archive template for that. You simply have to add an `author.php` file to your theme folder: http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates

And than you can use all author functions like:

- `get_the_author()` for the author name
- `get_the_author_meta('description')` for the description
- `get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('ID'), 40 )` for the avatar
- ...

There are also archives for categories (http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates) and Tags (http://codex.wordpress.org/Tag_Templates) btw.